# Strange Bug Need Help Identifying Issue - Possible Timing / Co-routine Issue? Unity3D - C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-development, timing

I've been experiencing really strange **behaviour** with a **pathfinding** algorithm I've written. Basically, this method is called recursively:

[image]
Until the path between the player and the enemy is found. This is the desired result:

[image]

It works fine. I thought I was all finished. Then I removed a delay I put in for testing and changed the method from a coroutine to a standard method. After removing the delay, I get this strange **behaviour**:

[image]

It generates a COMPLETELY different path and doesn't even bother to check to the East. No other code has changed at all. The black blocks represent impassable terrain. I've spent hours trying to work out what's going on but it just keeps getting stranger. It's so hard to debug this as whenever I add in a delay to see what's going on it fixes itself...

I will seriously pay anyone who can help me out here. Also, it doesn't matter how long the delay is. The **pathfinding** method is called when the player reaches the aggro range of the mob. The algorithm I'm using for **pathfinding** is a variant of Wavefront I think it's called.

Comment: How are you calling `checkAllCellDirections` exactly? Which parts are async?

Comment: Everything is called from the same class. So it's not some complicated architecture where there are lots of things interacting. GeneratePath(startPosX, startPosY) is called on Awake in the Grid Manager class. CheckAllCellDirections is then called from here: https://gyazo.com/6e6ed473a9549bb42323f526ab37e072

Comment: So checkAllCellDirections is not called recursively as you mentioned?

Comment: @schneebuzz. Yes, it is. Generate path starts the recursive call. GeneratePath called on Awake:

https://gyazo.com/dd5690a5d231fa0d6e02350c2a19ead2

Starts recursive call for:

https://gyazo.com/41aa656bea9e9171e84f998e368be0dc

South Check (all directional checks are similar):

https://gyazo.com/72d377e8b829a1a0a72d285d0b5e4cc0

Comment: Ah, now I see where the recursive call is happening. My guess is that in case of delay: The first call of checkAllCellDirections waits, then calls all direction checks which in turn may call checkAllCellDirections. Now with the delay, all direction-check calls "have enough time" to run once creating one iteration (each direction checked once). In case there is no delay, the first direction check call might call checkAllCellDirections again for the next stepNumber without letting the other directionChecks run.

Comment: As soon as the first check finds a player, the others are skipped even if its not the optimal path (due to `if(playerFound)return;`).

Comment: Yes, the first path found is always optimal anyway because cost of moving between each cell is equal. I still don't understand what this bug is. Unless it's a bug with the Unity game engine itself? I'm getting all sorts of weird behaviour. I'm starting to think there really is a ghost in the machine. Waiting for a single frame seems to fix it so I guess I'll have to just leave that terrible hack fix and hope this doesn't affect anything else. In my head the algorithm works perfectly. Usually when I get a bug I can eventually see the problem. Here everything makes no sense.

Comment: Not sure if you got my point or maybe I'm wrong but: if there is a delay, checkSouth is called (inner recursive call waits again) then checkNorth is called (inner recursive call waits again) then checkEast is called and so on, only then the next set of 4 direction checks is called again. However if there is no delay it is really hard to tell the call order. Check south can go directly in checkAllCellDirections again (with different count variables) and call checkSouth again without the former (recursionDepth - 1) call to checkAllCellDir had a chance to call the other three direction checks. Th

Comment: The order can get messed up because there is no sync mechanism like the waiting.

Comment: Yes, that may be the issue. I might be misunderstanding your point but even when it's a single thread (sequential execution) and there is no delay, I still get this strange behaviour. It feels like a concurrency problem but how can it be when I'm using a single thread. Anyway, thanks for sparing your time to help me out bud. Appreciated.